# vue-meta / Inertia: Title is 'undefined' between page rendering

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using Vue 2.6.12, Laravel and Inertia.

When using vue-meta to alter the meta title it displays 'undefined' for a split second when loading any page.

Im using Inertia, so the routing is on Laravels side and uses Inertia to pass the Vue component name and data to the frontend.

```js
//app.js
new Vue({
    metaInfo: {
        titleTemplate: 'Inertia: %s'
    },
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        },
    }),
}).$mount(el)

//Index.vue
export default {
    metaInfo: {
        title: 'User list'
    }
}
```

It generally works, but it seems to stop working while Inertia requests are being processed / recieved / sent.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

what I understood that you want to load and manipulate metadata of the html page.

This cannot be manipulated unless you create a slot in the header, or place a prop so that each time you pass parameters to it it changes, with a layout.!

the most ideal thing would be that you use it inside the router:

```
    const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      title: 'Home Page - Example App',
      metaTags: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'The home page of our example app.'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: 'The home page of our example app.'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

i dont expert in english.! will it really help
[enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-router-modify-head)

Comment: I used `vue-meta` to handle the metadata manipulation. The problem is that it shows `undefined` between page switches. It does work as intended in general.